# tutorialspoint's simple web browser using tcpsocket

Tags: ruby, tcpsocket

This piece of code supposedly gets the content of any web page:

```
require 'socket'

host = 'www.tutorialspoint.com'     # The web server
port = 80                           # Default HTTP port
path = "/index.htm"                 # The file we want 

# This is the HTTP request we send to fetch a file
request = "GET #{path} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"

socket = TCPSocket.open(host,port)  # Connect to server
socket.print(request)               # Send request
response = socket.read              # Read complete response
# Split response at first blank line into headers and body
headers,body = response.split("\r\n\r\n", 2) 
puts headers
puts body
```

When I run it in the command line, I get a 404 Error, but when i go to www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm it's there, so what gives?:

[404 Error Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu8zB.png)

Although, I don't have trouble using the open-uri library to get the contents of a web page. But I want to know how to use this one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request misses the Host parameter:

```
host = 'www.tutorialspoint.com'     # The web server
port = 80                           # Default HTTP port
path = "/index.htm"                 # The file we want 

# This is the HTTP request we send to fetch a file
request = "GET #{path} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: #{host}\r\n\r\n"
```

Note that apparently not all and every webserver require the "Host:" line (but see comments).

Comment: It worked, I wonder why the tutorial is missing the one crucial thing. Thanks, I'll keep in mind that some needs a host line.

Comment: It's true that not all servers require the `Host` header, however [the HTTP protocol standard **does** require the `Host` header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23). A security aware server should respond with error 400 (bad request) and terminate a connection when a request doesn't provide the `Host` header.

Comment: @JosefTinagan: Probably you should notifiy the tutorial site owner/editor.